# Disposal of sulfuric acid in baking soda

Tags: chemicals

I have about 20 ml of sulfuric acid I saw in a similar post that baking soda could be added to stop sulfuric acid from evaporating I was wondering if I put baking soda in a glass container and pour the sulfuric acid in then dilute with water if any reactions would occur I know it says to add the sulfuric acid to water just not the other way around but I'm trying to be extremely safe I almost burned my house down this weekend :P

Comment: I am not sure if this qualifies as DIY.

Comment: It's definitely DIY, but it's not [diy.se]... Also, there's no question, there are no actual sentences...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Home Improvement within the scope of what's [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Note that "sulfuric acid " doesn't say anything about how concentrated it is....

Comment: "I know it says add the acid to water, BUT I'm trying to be extremely safe so I'm ignoring good advice" and "I already had an accident so my judgment isn't exactly proven reliable here".  <------ things trolls say

Answer (score 4):

If you add baking soda you don't have sulphuric acid anymore. You'll have sodium sulphate, carbon dioxide and water.

Sodium sulphate is a salt, and will likely show us as crystals during the neutralization. It's more or less harmless compared to sulphuric acid. Don't eat it, and don't inhale it.

For 20 ml I'd probably just dilute it in a bucket of water and pour it out...

Comment: "dilute in a bucket of water" is right - "dilute with water" wouldn't be.  Pouring the acid into copious amounts of water means the water absorbs the large amounts of heat generated, while pouring water into the acid would be a bad idea (e.g. if there's 20ml left in a 100ml bottle don't be tempted to add water to the bottle).  Once diluted it could be neutralised with bicarb if you wanted

Answer (score 0):

I would just pour it onto dry, bare soil and then spread baking soda liberally on top of it (a tablespoon plus).  Leave for a few minutes and hose it down.

Otherwise you risk it spurting onto your face.